# How to fix git after double reset

Tags: git

I have reset the master to one commit back and then I have reset back to current commit as I have changed my mind. I am not sure how/when I pushed the commits to remote git repo on github but now I am in a situation I cannot push to remote with the current MASTER branch - I can but the remote looks like I haven't pushed any changes("Everything up-to-date"). I have tried to pull and merge but without success - no difference is detected. Any ideas about how to fix this?

Your help is much appreciated. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmVF9.jpg

Comment: Did you try `git fetch` to update your remote branches?

Comment: Looks like you already have pushed commits to github and now there are no new changes made. try updating something different  (different files etc.??)

Comment: @poke
I have tried `git fetch` it just now and then I tried `merge` I got `fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set`. Then I fixed it but nothing has changed. :-/

Comment: Have you tried to `push --force` ?

If you want understand what happens, results of `git branch -avv` and `git log --graph --pretty=tformat:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%an %cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --cherry-mark --left-only master...origin/master` (graph, pretty, abbrev-commit and date are only cosmetics options here) should help to understand.

Comment: @alexscott 

I can push but I am being told there is no difference between local MASTER and remote origin so `--force` option hasn't changed anything

after running `git branch -avv` I got

* MASTER e216687 [origin/master: ahead 1] Add Receipts to Claim Request, Edit not working on Requests
  remotes/bitbucket/master 02abafb Add mcamara localization without configuration
  remotes/origin/master    a6128f7 Add multiple Receipt type tables and models

and after the second command I got:
* e216687 - (HEAD, MASTER) Add Receipts to Claim Request, Edit not working on Requests (0re1 2 hours ago)

Comment: @user2954584, when you do `git ls-remote origin` have you :  02abafb[...] HEAD and 02abafb[...] refs/heads/master ?

Comment: @alexscott
no I have:
a6128f7a0db670fe99b6c63bd3dd0bfbbc9b7ccc        HEAD
a6128f7a0db670fe99b6c63bd3dd0bfbbc9b7ccc        refs/heads/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started git extensions and run the `push` command from `MASTER` to `MASTER` and the push WORKED! Previously I have run just `git push` or `git push MASTER` on command line and that hasn't worked at all.

Comment: The correct command from the command line would have been `git push origin master`.